# How can I create a seek command in my discord music bot? (Discord.py rewrite)

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have searched everywhere but I could not find any solution to my problem.
I just want to make a command by which I can forward the currently playing music to a certain timestamp.
I am using discord.py 1.6.0.

Comment: What do you mean by "seek"? As in a google/youtube search? Is the bot playing the music or someone else? Do you want something like the Shazam app? Or are you trying to forward the song to a certain timestamp?

Comment: I want to forward song to a certain timestamp.

Comment: Figure out a conversion rate between frame count and minutes in the track, kill the current player and start reading from that frame. Pretty sure if you look around you can find source code for other bots what can skip timestamps.